# Unable to click on a <div href="#"> HTML element using Appium AndroidDriver in WebView context

Tags: android, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing an Android Hybrid application using Appium v1.3.4 (REV c8c79a85fbd6870cd6fc3d66d038a115ebe22efe) which is the lastest at the moment. I also downloaded the latest ChromeDriver from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/iBdJQHu1ipQ

The login screen in the application under test is a hybrid view (WebView). So I am switching to the proper context via calling appiumDriver.context("WEBVIEW_com.my.app.pkg")as shown below and I am also able to successfully locate and populate both the username and the password fields with the proper text data using the following code:

```
appiumDriver.context("WEBVIEW_com.my.app.pkg");

WebElement userNameTextField = appiumDriver.findElement(By.id("username"));
userNameTextField.click();
userNameTextField.sendKeys(new String[]{"Guest"});

WebElement passwordTextField = appiumDriver.findElement(By.id("password"));
passwordTextField.click();
passwordTextField.sendKeys(new String[]{"password"});

// The following code is not working
WebElement loginButton = appiumDriver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton"));
loginButton.click();
```

However, my issue is when I try to click on the login button on this screen! This is how the button is written in HTML

```
<div href="#" id="loginbutton" class="button">Login</div>
```

I tried many ways to click on the button while I am in the Web context but all so far has been in vain...This is the HTML snippet for the login screen

```
<div id="formbody">
  <div class="line">
        <input placeholder="Username" type="text" id="username" class="styled_input" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="line">
        <input placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password" class="styled_input" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="line_button">
        <div href="#" id="loginbutton" class="button">Login</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

After many many attempts to click on the div/link in the Webcontext, I gave up and switched to the NATIVE context and was able to click on the button using the following code:

```
appiumDriver.context("NATIVE_APP");
appiumDriver.findElementByName("Login").click();
```

Can anyone explain to me why I am able to interact with the username and password textfields in the WebView context but have to switch to the NATIVE_APP context to be able to interact with the button?

Also note that while in the WebView context I am able to find the button ... tag by id and to call loginButton.getText(), loginButton.isEnabled(), loginButton.isDisplayed() and getTagName()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"formbody\"]/div[3]")).click();
```

should work. Inspect elements on your device using chrome, this will give you exact xpath.
To inspect elements, type this command in chrome:   `chrome://inspect/#devices`